# Pass by reference troubles

Tags: c#, pass-by-reference

So recently I discovered that you can change a variable by passing it to another class object, then changing the newly received value will change the initial value.
I must apologize as I know I've very poorly explained this. Here was my test to see whether or not it worked, and it did.

class Program
    {
        static objectA a;
        static objectB b;

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        a = new objectA();
        b = new objectB(a);

        Console.WriteLine(a.v + "\n");
        Console.WriteLine(b.b.v + "\n");

        a.v = 5;

        Console.WriteLine(a.v + "\n");
        Console.WriteLine(b.b.v + "\n");

        b.b.v = 7;

        Console.WriteLine(a.v + "\n");
        Console.WriteLine(b.b.v + "\n");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class objectB
{
    public objectB(objectA b)
    {
        this.b = b;
    }

    public objectA b;
}

class objectA
{
    public objectA()
    {
        v = 0;
    }

    public int v;
}
```

I played about with this in a project featuring particles and a particle engine and it worked wonderfully, but then I tried something else and I'm a little lost.

I have class A which inherits class B which inherits abstract class C.

Main class initializes class A and passes it a value which it stores in class C.

Unlike my test, when I edit the value in the main class, the value doesn't change in class C.

```
class MainExample { 
private vector2 position = new vector2(175, 135);
private ship_ShipName ship_();
...
     public MainExample()
     {
          ship_ = new ship_ShipName(position);
          ...

      }
}

class ship_ShipName : Ship
{
     public ship_ShipName(vector2 position)
     {
          this.position = position; //this.position being the position from Module.cs
     }
}

class Ship : Module { ... }
abstract class Module { vector2 position; }
```

Looking at my particle engine now I see it's not abstract, so the problem must relate to that. Any insight is utmost appreciated and I am right to think what I'm describing is 'passing by reference?' Thanks.

Comment: You're passing everything by value in the code above.

Comment: If you want us to analyze why your program is doing what it is, then show it to us.  Without seeing what you're doing, we can only guess at why you're seeing results you don't expect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no pass-by-reference going on anywhere in the sample code you posted. You are constructing two distinct objects, `a` and `b`. Those objects are independent and changes to properties/fields in one will not be reflected in the other.

You may be thinking that this line is creating a reference:

```
b = new objectB(a);
```

It's not. It's creating a new object, invoking `objectB`'s constructor passing `a` as an argument (and it's passed by value).

*EDIT based on OP clarification*

I think the difference between your test program and the real code you posted is that in the real code, `vector2` is a `struct`. Structs are value-types in C# unlike classes which are reference types. In your test code, when you passed `a` to the constructor for `b`, the argument is a class, so the reference type is passed by reference. In your real code, a copy of the `vector2` is being made.

You can add the `ref` keyword to pass the value to the constructor by reference. However, a copy will still be made when you assign that to your local field. There is no easy way to fix this. The best way would be to create a `class` wrapper type which holds the vector, and then all parties hold references to a single instance of the wrapper object.

Comment: It passes the value of the reference to `a` in the constructor of `b`. It probably assigns the value of top-level `a` to an internal variable called `b` of type `objectA` and he's changing `v` of `a`. This is reflected by `b.b.v`.

Comment: Possibly. No way to know for sure unless OP posts the code for classes `objectA` and `objectB`...

Comment: I've updated the OP will the full code. Sorry for causing confusion and thanks for the help, everyone.

Comment: Is `vector2` a `struct`?

Comment: ... probably. Updated my answer to explain why that would make a difference. Thanks for clarifying the question.

Comment: Got it working using the class wrapper, thanks David :)

Answer (score -2):

Classes are pass by reference. They are pointer to that class. Class parameters are not copied. So if you change that parameter class' fields, that outside class' fields will change. There is a single instance of class.

Cloning is copying a class (create two different classes).

Comment: Nope. There is no "pass-by-reference" unless the parameter is `ref` or `out`.